What is the difference between an intermetallic alloy and an interstitial alloy?
For example if an Boron forms an alloy with Vanadium is it an interstitial or an intermetallic alloy? And why?

Well, there are 6 known intermediate phases in the B-V binary phase diagram. Most have narrow (at best) phase fields, so I personally would not describe any of them as an interstitial alloy. For clarity, I consider something like TiN to be an interstitial alloy - the Ti sublattice is filled, and the N atoms occupy interstitial positions of the Ti sublattice, and the N occupancy can vary widely resulting in a large phase field.

Interstitial compounds are formed when lighter atoms (H, B, C, N) occupy interstitial positions in the crystal sub-structure formed by metallic atoms. For example, some amounts of N can be dissolved into Nb forming a solid solution with the same crystal structure of pure Nb (body-centered cubic structure). If you increase the amount of N, new compounds form with peculiar crystal structures, such as Nb2N (hexagonal) and NbN (face-centered cubic).
Intermetallic alloys are formed between metallic elements; in this case, the atomic sizes of metal atoms are comparable. It follows that in no alloy or intermetallic compound is it possible to obtain a sub-structure capable of having interstitial sites sufficiently voluminous to accommodate other metallic elements.
Phases belonging to the V-B system are interstitial compounds (not alloys).

Do you have a reference for this terminology?

If you're asking for a specific scientific publication, I would say [Goldschmidt, Interstitial Alloys (1967)] and [Toth, Transition Metal Carbides and Nitrides, Academic, New York (1971)]. A more recent publication can be found here [https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Walter-Lengauer/publication/227554988_Nitrides_Transition_Metal_Solid-State_Chemistry/links/5a06ea61aca272ed279cb521/Nitrides-Transition-Metal-Solid-State-Chemistry.pdf]

Just to be clear, my question comes after wrestling with more than a thousand binary phase diagrams over the years, so I've seen more of the mess behind the curtain than many. Lets take Ti-N. Both hcp and bcc (the stable pure phases of Ti) show substantial solubility of N (hcp more than bcc) and they indeed occupy interstitial sites which allows the broad phase field. Similarly TiN has an fcc Ti structure with again interstitial N with wide solubility. Cool. Then there is Ti2N, a line compound, which is inverse rutile where the N really can't be thought of as interstitial.

To be clear too, my answer comes from years of preparation and study of transition metal nitrides. You asked for references and I put some quite authoritative ones in my previous answer. When you’re referring to Ti2N, I guess you mean the epsilon phase (it’s the only one with stoichiometry). Actually, this is not a line compound, as you see here [Lengauer, Acta Metall. Mater. 39 (1991) 2985; see fig. 8-9, for example].

However, I can't follow your reasoning (or rather, I follow it up to a certain point) when you write “…is inverse rutile where the N really can't be thought of as interstitial”. Please explain why you state this.
